# Set magic line width to the anchor not the list item

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I am using a magic line and I get it working, but the width of the magic line is taking the width of the `<li>` element, but I want it to take the width of the `<a>` element. Can anyone help me edit the jquery code to do this?

Here is the html:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text text text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text text text text</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#menu-main-menu {
  display: flex;
}

#menu-main-menu li {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

#menu-main-menu li a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#magic-line {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

jquery (sorry about the length)

```
jQuery(function() {

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
        $mainNav = jQuery("#menu-main-menu");

    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = jQuery("#magic-line");

    if( jQuery('#menu-main-menu .current-menu-ancestor').length ) {
        var currentPageWidth = jQuery('#menu-main-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a').parent().width();
        var currentPageLeft = jQuery('#menu-main-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a').parent().position().left;
    }

    if( jQuery('#menu-main-menu .current-menu-item').length ) {
        var currentPageWidth = jQuery('#menu-main-menu .current-menu-item > a').parent().width();
        var currentPageLeft = jQuery('#menu-main-menu .current-menu-item > a').parent().position().left;
    }

    $magicLine
        .width(currentPageWidth)
        .css("left", currentPageLeft)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    jQuery("#menu-main-menu li").hover(function() {
        $el = jQuery(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });

    jQuery("#menu-main-menu li .sub-menu li").hover(function() {
        $magicLine.stop()
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });
}, 1500);
```

and the jsfiddle

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/379ndhwb/1/)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the line supposed to get wider as you mouse over links that are wider? Or the line just stays the same width all the time?

Comment: it should change width depending on the width of the anchor tag

Comment: I have tried, with leftPos = $el.position().left + $el.children().position().left ;
newWidth = $el.children().width(); and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this

```
jQuery("#menu-main-menu li").hover(function() {
            $el = jQuery(this);
            leftPos = $el.position().left;
            newWidth = $el.width();
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: leftPos,
                width: newWidth
            });
        }, function() {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
            });
        });
```

into

```
jQuery("#menu-main-menu li").hover(function() {
            $el = jQuery(this);
            leftPos = $el.position().left + $el.children().position().left ;
            newWidth = $el.children().width();
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: leftPos,
                width: newWidth
            });
        }, function() {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[I forked your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk49j3vp/2/).

A note before we start: for simplicity, I stripped out parts of your function not related to the actual markup included in the fiddle, but you may need to modify what you had if it's relevant to your actual project.

So the first problem was that the variables `currentPageWidth` and `currentPageLeft` were undefined because there was no element in the HTML matching their definition. Since you wanted the width of the link and not the `li`, I created new variables for this purpose:

```
var linkWidth = $($mainNav).find('li:first-child a').width();
var linkLeft = $($mainNav).find('li:first-child a').offset().left;
```

Then we update the hover function to refer to the links within each `li` instead of the `li` directly:

```
jQuery($mainNav).find('li').hover(function() {
  leftPos = jQuery(this).find('a').offset().left;
  newWidth = jQuery(this).find('a').width();
  ...
```

Finally, I changed your use of `.position()` to `.offset()` so that we would get the left distance of each link relative to the document. Left positioning did not seem to work as intended with `.position()` after the above changes were made.

(Also I changed the hover function to use the `$mainNav` variable you had already created.)

Hope that helps.

```js
jQuery(function() {

        var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
            $mainNav = jQuery("#menu-main-menu");

        $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
        var $magicLine = jQuery("#magic-line");
        
        var linkWidth = $($mainNav).find('li:first-child a').width();
        var linkLeft = $($mainNav).find('li:first-child a').offset().left;

        $magicLine
            .width(linkWidth)
            .css("left", linkLeft)
            .data("origLeft", $magicLine.offset().left)
            .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

          jQuery($mainNav).find('li').hover(function() {
              leftPos = jQuery(this).find('a').offset().left;
              newWidth = jQuery(this).find('a').width();
              $magicLine.stop().animate({
                  left: leftPos,
                  width: newWidth
              });
          }, function() {
              $magicLine.stop().animate({
                  left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
                  width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
              });
          });

    }, 1500);
```

```css
#menu-main-menu {
  display: flex;
}

#menu-main-menu li {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

#menu-main-menu li a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#magic-line {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
    <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text text text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">text text text text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: great explanation, thank you for your answer, I already accepted another answer but i will upvote you